# What is the maximum number of subscribers I can include in a REST API request for a triggered send?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to use Salesforce to kick off triggered send e-mail via the ExactTarget REST API.  How many e-mails can I send over in the JSON per API request?  Also, is there a maximum number of transactional e-mails I can send per day, or a maximum number of API requests I can make in an hour/day/whatever time frame?  Is using sendBatch an option/requirement here?

I'm accustomed to limitations on activities like this within Salesforce but haven't read much on any such limitations when working with ExactTarget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its only designed to handle one subscriber.  As far as I know there is no limit on the rest of the your questions (although, please don't try and prove me wrong.)

What you probably would want to do is set up a triggered automation in automation studio, and do your sends that way.  You would design everything in the email part of the app, then go over to Automation Studio to set up the automation.  That will give you the flexibility you're looking for.

Comment: I am pretty sure most apps are limited to 500k calls/day. It says somewhere in the HubApps page.